# Get background-image url value

Tags: javascript, html, url, background-image

I have 7 divs each one with a different background-image and I need to get the url of each background image passed inline in the html, can someone help me with that?

I've tried different ways but with no success :(

Comment: Please post the code you have and what you tried.

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle of the HTML code

Comment: Have you tried [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) or [jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName)?

Comment: also explain what you want to do with it. Will be returned  with `url('path/to/image')` format

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/e46bf/

use .each to cycle through all the div, to get background images.

```
$("div").each(
    function(index) {
        var thisUrl = $(this).css("backgroundImage");
        var content = $("p").html(); // current content
        $("p").html(content+" "+thisUrl);
    }
);
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this is using jQuery, since the question isn't tagged with it.